# How to programatically and dynamically (I don't know N of columns of the ListView at compile time) add items to a ListView in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, gridview

**I can't use Bindings (ListView.ItemSource), and I also have to add columns programatically, not with XAML**

Said that, this is the question
Is possible to fill cells of a ListView, programatically (in C#) and dynamically (I don't know how many columns will have the ListView until runtime)?

This is what i got so far:

```xml
<ListView Name="listView" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Margin="0 10 0 0"/>
```

```cs
listView.Items.Clear();

listViewGridView.Columns.Clear();
listViewGridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn() { Header = "Host", Width = 150 });

foreach (string field in fields) // fields is a List<string> containing several fields, but unknown how many, each represents a column (there is a extra hardcoded column "Hosts" that contains another field)
{
    listViewGridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn() { Header = field, Width = 150 });
}

listView.View = listViewGridView;

foreach (Host host in engine.hostList) // engine.hostList is other List<string> containing a unknown number of Hosts, each one will be represented with a row
{
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
    item.Content = host.toArray();
    listView.Items.Add(item); // The result of this, is string "String[] Array" in all cells (all rows and columns)
    //listView.Items.Add(Host.host); // Also tried to add just the hardcoded field, as string, this results on the string printed on all cells of the row
}
```

I remember that in Windows Forms, I could use ListViewItem.Subitems for this, but is not included in WPF

Hope that was sufficient information, thanks for listening to me. Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you want to generate columns for all the properties you can use a `DataGrid` instead and set the `AutoGenerateColumns` to true. That would generate everything for you once you've assigned the `ItemsSource` property.